# Why form is not submitting on Ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, ajax

I have the following code whereby it validates an array and if the array is empty, it should submit a form called `deleteUnitManagement`. Else it should show a modal with the array values in it. Here the `errorFunction` is a modal.

```js
$("#deleteUnitButton").click(function() {
  if ($("#deleteUnit").val().trim().length == 0) { //If unit field is empty
    $("#deleteUnit").css("border-color", "red");
    er("Please select a Unit name");
    errorFunction("Error in Processing", "Please select a Unit name");
    return false;
  } else if ($("#deleteUnit").val() == "Not Applicable") {
    er("This is a default unit name selection. Cannot delete");
    errorFunction("Error in Processing", "This is a default unit name selection. Cannot delete");
    return false;
  } else { //The following Ajax is checking if there is an existing user present with the unit that selected to delete. If there is then it will ask to change those users unit to some other units before do this deleting operation
    var unitNum = $("#deleteUnit").val();
    var isThereUser = false;

    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "unitCheck.php",
      data: {
        unitNum: unitNum
      },
      success: function(result) {
        var returnedData = JSON.parse(result);
        var length = returnedData.length;
        var users = "";
        if (length != 0) {
          isThereUser = true;
          for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            if (i == 0) {
              users = users + returnedData[i];
            } else {
              users = users + ", " + returnedData[i];
            }
          }
          errorFunction("Error in Processing", "There are " + length + " user(s) (" + users + ") assigned to this floor. Please change their units first before deleting this unit");

        } else {
          $("#deleteUnit").css("border-color", "");
          $("#deleteUnitManagement").submit();
        }
      }
    });
    return false;
  }

});
```

Following is the codes in `unitCheck.php`

```
$unitNum = $_POST['unitNum'];
$userNames = [];

$query = "SELECT userName FROM users WHERE userUnit=?";
$stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
if(!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $query)){
    echo "Selecting user names from users table query failed";
}else{
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt,"s", $unitNum);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
}
while($rows = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    $name = $rows['userName'];
    array_push($userNames, $name);
}
echo json_encode($userNames);
```

The code is working fine for conditions whereby array is not empty. It will pop up modal window with all the array values. But if the array is empty, it is not submitting the form. Does anyone know why?

**Edit 1**

Simplified code with no `Ajax` and included all `HTML` elements. You can comment out `returnedData` variable lines to enable and disable empty and non empty condition. Over here also if the array is not empty, it is alerting elements in that array. But once it is empty, the form is not submitting and showing echoing message `deleted`

```js
$("#deleteUnitButton").click(function() {
  var returnedData = [];
  //        var returnedData = ["sdfs", "sdfdssf"];
  var length = returnedData.length;

  var users = "";
  if (length != 0) {
    isThereUser = true;
    for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
      if (i == 0) {
        users = users + returnedData[i];
      } else {
        users = users + ", " + returnedData[i];
      }
    }
    alert(users);
  } else {
    $("#deleteUnit").css("border-color", "");
    $("#deleteUnitManagement").submit();
  }
  return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js" integrity="sha256-WpOohJOqMqqyKL9FccASB9O0KwACQJpFTUBLTYOVvVU=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="col-sm-3">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-body">
      <div style="padding:20px;">
        <h3 class="text-center"><img src="" id="">Delete Unit</h3>
      </div>
      <form method="post" id="deleteUnitManagement" name="deleteUnitManagement">
        <button type="submit" id="deleteUnitButton" name="deleteUnitButton" class="btn btn-danger">Delete Unit</button>
      </form>
      <?php
            if(isset($_POST['deleteUnitButton'])){
                echo 'deleted';  
            }
        ?>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What array exactly? I see no array in your code

Comment: okay. I will post the codes in `unitCheck.php` too so that it will be clear

Comment: No, PHP is irrelevant here. You're saying your problem is the validation before the ajax call

Comment: Here the `returnedData` is an array returned from the Ajax call

Comment: Please change your code into a [mcve]. Remove the AJAX request from your code (at least the code you post here in your question), only leave the success handler. Then check what your PHP returns and hard-code that into the `result` string, so we can get the same result without making the actual AJAX request. Then also add the relevant HTML so that we can reproduce the problem ourselves.

Comment: @Ivar Let me see if i can reproduce by doing that way

Comment: @Ivar I submitted the simplified code in my edit

Comment: @Anu Your example seems to submit fine for me.

Comment: @Ivar Have you tried by keeping `returnedData` as empty array? For me it is only working if I kept `returnedData` as non empty. But at this condition, it is only alerting things. But the moment I kept empty array, it is not echoing anything as expected.

Comment: I ran your snippet. Try it yourself. Hit the blue "Run code snippet" button and hit the submit button and you'll see that it navigates away from that post (the form is submitted).

Comment: But it is not echoing 'deleted' as expected. So it seems not executing the `isset($_POST['deleteUnitButton'])` code which is the form submit. I tried in a separate server whereby it can execute `php` as well

Comment: I think the catch is at the `return false` statement. I think I should give `return false` at the first condition whereby array is not empty

Comment: @Anu The code snippets at Stack Overflow don't run any PHP, so it will never show you PHP output. In your code it doesn't work because (IIRC) buttons don't send any value to the server so `$_POST['deleteUnitButton']` will not be set. Change it to `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST'` and you will see that it indeed send a POST request (and thus the form is submitted).

Comment: @Ivar I already set the form method as `POST`. So is it needed to set request method to post again?

Comment: @Anu The form is submitted with the POST method yes, but your PHP code doesn't detect that. Change `if(isset($_POST['deleteUnitButton']))` to `if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST')` so that your if-statement is entered when a POST request is made. `isset($_POST['deleteUnitButton'])` doesn't work because no `deleteUnitButton` value is send to your server.

Comment: It works perfect. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Ivar I have one more doubt about `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST'`. What if there are multiple buttons in the form? How can we specify which `if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST')` should execute?

Comment: If you have multiple buttons on the form, you can use an `<input type="submit" name="name" value="value">` with a name and value of your choice. The name and value of the submit button you clicked will be send to the server so you can then check for those. Otherwise you could also add a `formaction` attribute with that will submit the data to a different URL (defined in the value of the `formaction`). And of course you could also have two separate forms and use different `action`s or add a `<input type="hidden"` with a custom name and value and check for those.

Comment: @Ivar So for this case, lets say if i want to target the button `deleteUnitButton`; inside if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') condition, I would have to check another condition if(isset($_POST['deleteUnitButton'])). Is it what you said?

Comment: Yep. As long as your button is something in the lines of `<input type="submit" name="deleteUnitButton" value="any value">`.